# JavaME odd and confusing documentation

Tags: oracle, java-me, xlet

Oracles Forum about JavaME is dead! I'm sorry to say, but questions never get an answer. 
The javaME-GettingstartedGuide.pdf from Oracle tells me: The GPIO pins are preconfigured! Does this mean I must take it as it is and JavaME does not allow any configuration? Further, the document tells me Device ID 1, named GPIO4 is input only and mapped to pin 4! But the Pi documentation tells me Pin 4 is connected to +5V! Where can I find valid information?

Answer (score 0):

The problem relies in the two kind of numbering. A Raspberry style (Broadcom pin number) and raspberry physical style! You can find both in the JavaME-GettingStartedGuid, but not side by side. A problem in a GettingStartedGuid. Not being prepared you get confused! [See Raspberry Pi Pinout](http://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin13_gpio27#)

The question w.r.t. Pin reconfiguration in JavaME however ist still open.